# enable c# parallel class

Tags: c#

i have a visual studio 2008, using c#

wanted to get parallel class.

added                 using System.Threading;

but no parallel class appears, can you help me to get it? thanks!

Comment: Be more specific about what you're trying to do and what you mean by "parallel."

Comment: I think he's trying to use the new System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel class that's part of .NET 4 (and backported into the Rx framework for 3.5sp1).

Comment: Can you please not hit <return> every 5 seconds when asking a question? I understand your spacing is based on how you would say this question if speaking, but please remember that you are writing, not speaking, and that to be legible you have to use different conventions than is you were trying to be audible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1) You need to be using .NET 4 with VS 2010, or download the [Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) (which includes a backported version of the TPL) in order to use the Parallel class.

2) As of .NET 4, beta 1, the Parallel class is now part of the [System.Threading.Tasks namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(VS.100).aspx), not part of System.Threading.  The Rx Framework also includes it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is only available in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only in .Net 4.0.